# text cropped android textView

Tags: android, textview

I got 4 textview, their size depends on guidelines, the placement of the guidelines is correct since it's already used all over the project. I tried many solutions but none of them helped me solving my problem. My text is always cropped, no matter the size of the screen, the font size or the text.

[image]

I looked for options that auto resize textfield text's font depending on the size of the container but it didn't worked for me.

Here is the result I am looking for.

[image]

those textviews are custom textview extending `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` but no modification is done to the text itself so far.

EDIT : here is my custom class

```
public class MyTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private Context context = null;
    private AttributeSet attrs = null;


    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.context = context;
        this.attrs = attrs;

        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

here is the xml

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:id="@+id/TopOf"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.031200000000000002" />
                        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:id="@+id/StartOf"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />
                        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:id="@+id/BottomOf"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9062" />
                        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:id="@+id/EndOf"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.16477" />
                        <com.customView.MyTextView
android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
android:fontFamily="roboto"

android:text="Downloads" 
android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
android:textSize="8dp"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/StartOf"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TopOf"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/EndOf"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/BottomOf" />
```

Comment: share you code, show what you did?

Comment: Add your code and xml part .

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of textview

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="text" />
```